# Firebase Invalid Notification small icon

Tags: android, push-notification

I am trying to show notification in the app. App show notification when background or foreground  But the App crash when app not clear from app background stack. I don't know why it happens. below is my app notification code Any Help will be Appreciated.

```
if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
    notif = (new android.app.Notification.Builder(this, this.getString(string.notification_channel_id))).setSmallIcon(notificationResId).setContentTitle(title).setStyle((new BigTextStyle()).bigText(this.mText == null ? "" : this.mText)).setContentText(this.mText == null ? "" : this.mText).setVisibility(0).setChannelId(this.getString(string.notification_channel_id)).setAutoCancel(true);
} else {
    mBuilder = (new Builder(this)).setContentTitle(title).setSmallIcon(notificationResId).setStyle((new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()).bigText(this.mText == null ? "" : this.mText)).setContentText(this.mText == null ? "" : this.mText).setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(-1);
}

if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
    notif.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    this.mNotificationManager.notify(id, notif.build());
} else {
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    this.mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
}
```

**Error:**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=default sound=default defaults=0xffffffff flags=0x11 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE semFlags=0x0 semPriority=0)

Comment: check that notificationResId is valid (it's not)

Comment: @TimCastelijns it's working when the app in backgroud.. but crash when removing background stack.

Answer (score 0):

Add this meta in your manifest in 'application'

```
<meta-data
         android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
         android:resource="@mipmap/ic_hello" />
```

Comment: I did this, but I still have this problem. In my case the icon is at the drawable folder instead of the mipmap, but I'm not sure that's the problem because it works on some devices and does not on others.

Comment: hi!, if you have notification control you could put the icon with notificationcompatbuilder like question but if firebase have the control of show notifications when the app is in background firebase will show this icon (metadata), but is your icon a svg format whithout background? or are you have all pack of images for all resolutions?

Comment: Hello Daniel. I indeed solved my problem using the setSmallIcon method from the notificationcompatbuilder, once the meta-data tag was not working everytime. I do not have a svg without background because my icon is too complex, but I do have an image (white png with blank background) for all resolutions (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi). I'm still not sure whats going on.

Comment: Great! I would like to share with you this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase (check the answer have 159 votes),  hoping it will help you a little bit with this